# Функции декораторы

Tags: javascript, функции, декоратор

Ниже приведён общий пример декоратора.У меня такой вопрос: 2й аргумент в декораторе "MyFunc" это и есть обёртка которую возвращает декоратор?

```
function f(x) {} // любая функция

var timers = {}; // объект для таймеров

// отдекорировали
f = timingDecorator(f, "myFunc");

// запускаем
f(1);
f(2);
f(3); // функция работает как раньше, но время подсчитывается

alert( timers.myFunc ); // общее время выполнения всех вызовов f
```

реализация с измерителем времени:

```
var timers = {};

// прибавит время выполнения f к таймеру timers[timer]
function timingDecorator(f, timer) {
  return function() {
    var start = performance.now();

    var result = f.apply(this, arguments); // (*)

    if (!timers[timer]) timers[timer] = 0;
    timers[timer] += performance.now() - start;

    return result;
  }
}

// функция может быть произвольной, например такой:
var fibonacci = function f(n) {
  return (n > 2) ? f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) : 1;
}

// использование: завернём fibonacci в декоратор
fibonacci = timingDecorator(fibonacci, "fibo");

// неоднократные вызовы...
alert( fibonacci(10) ); // 55
alert( fibonacci(20) ); // 6765
// ...

// в любой момент можно получить общее количество времени на вызовы
alert( timers.fibo + 'мс' );
```

Comment: Судя по использованию это просто имя поля в котором потом надо смотреть время 

Comment: чтобы понять что значит второй параметр, нужно смотреть что за функция timingDecorator

Comment: Я добавил пример  измерения времени работы функции фиббоначи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Декоратор возвращает новую функцию

```
function timingDecorator(f, timer) {
  return function() {
  ...
```

Второй аргумент в декораторе - это название свойства, которое создаётся декоратором в объекте `timers` и куда потом записывается общее время выполнения вызовов функций, которые прошли через декоратор с таким же вторым параметром.

```
...
if (!timers[timer]) timers[timer] = 0;
timers[timer] += performance.now() - start;
...
```

Чтобы это увидеть, в вашем же примере есть алерт

```
alert( timers.myFunc )
```